# iPod touch user agent detection

Tags: facebook, firefox, firefox-addon, user-agent

When someone updates his/her status on FB from iPod touch, FB automatically attributes its "via iPod touch".

With user agent switcher (like the one Firefox extension offers), I can fake the "via Mobile Web".

However, I am not successful with the via iPod touch. So the goal here is to fake our agent and hope to get via iPod touch even when we are on a regular PC.

Is it even possible?

I don't have an iPod touch myself. but this is something I filled out in the user agent switcher

```
Mozila/5.0 (iPod; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/3A101a Safari/419.3
```

I believe that those specific "via {device_name}" are done through its specific app. For example, via iPhone probably is done through iPhone's FB app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe that those specific "via {device_name}" are done through its specific app. For example, via iPhone probably is done through iPhone's FB app.

I believe you are correct. The only way you might be able to "fake" that would be to create your own app with the same name (or a similar name), or somehow steal the access keys out of the real app.